# XSL / XSLT making text and <xsl:for-each> bold

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XSL template, within that , I need a section to be bold or at least a heavier weight font / larger font.

```
Your name -
    <xsl:for-each select="date">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,25)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

So "Your Name" needs to be bold, but so does the dynamically generated "date" .

Ive tried wrapping the bold tags around etc. , but understand thats not how XSL really works. I cannot find a solution though. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What output are you transforming your XML to (HTML, FO/PDF etc etc)?

Comment: XSLT transforms XML trees. It doesn't render anything, neither bold nor red. If you properly rephrase this question, then the answer will become evident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be complete example can be helpful.

**XML:**

```
<t>
    <date>2010-10-02</date>
    <date>2010-10-02</date>
    <date>2010-10-02</date>
    <date>2010-10-02</date>
    <date>2010-10-02</date>
    <date>2010-10-02</date>
</t>
```

**XSL:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/t">
        <strong>
            <xsl:text>Your name - </xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="date">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,25)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </strong>
    </xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output as source code** (linebreak for clarity only):

```
<strong>Your name - 
2010-10-022010-10-022010-10-022010-10-022010-10-022010-10-02</strong>
```

**Output as rendered:**

**Your name - 2010-10-022010-10-022010-10-022010-10-022010-10-022010-10-02**

Comment: Thanks ! Had to edit it a bit ,the key was putting the <xsl:text> wrappers around the "Your Name" part.

Answer (score 0):

is this going to be rendered in HTML?

i am not an XSLT expert but I don't see anything wrong with wrapping the bold tags.

```
<h1>
Your name -
    <xsl:for-each select="date">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,25)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</h1>
```

Comment: thanks for  the answer, but that doesn't work, in the same way as bold doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean sth like:

```
Your name -
    <span style="font-weight:900">
       <xsl:for-each select="date">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,25)"/>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </span>
```

The 900 is the maximum. There are plenty of other possible values for the `font-weight` CSS attribute.  However from your question, I suspect the font-weight in parent element(s) is impacting the rendering of the whole excerpt.

Comment: Hi thanks, this fails also (just a blank page after the transform) Also note that "Your name" also needs to be in a bolder font too. Thanks.